# Elasticsearch NoNodeAvailableException issue

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

Our spring boot app is indexing data in ES cluster using transport client [using ElasticsearchRepository ]. Issue is that after some index call indexing just hangs the.the SAVE method on DAO just **hangs** and After some time it gives us "**Nonodefoundexception**"

Here’s our stack

- ES 1.7.3
- Spring Boot: 1.3.2.RELEASE
- Java: 1.8
- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch : 1.3.2.RELEASE

Using transport client:

**ES setup:**
- there are three nodes. all are client and master and data

**Environment:**
Our dev is in AWS and we do not see any issue in Dev even though all ES setup is same.

```
**org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes were available: [[NodeName-apsrp5470][TzlZ3u8aTK23YFr14R085g][apsrp5470][inet[/10.222.146.127:9300]]{master=true}, [NodeName-apsrp5434][K4r0wujuThqwj1oTU9lEHg][apsrp5434][inet[/10.222.146.132:9300]]{master=true}, [NodeName-apsrp5435][YBPk8E4TR6u7LFLxfaVWaw][apsrp5435][inet[/10.222.146.139:9300]]{master=true}]
at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService$RetryListener.onFailure(TransportClientNodesService.java:242) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar!/:na]
at org.elasticsearch.action.TransportActionNodeProxy$1.handleException(TransportActionNodeProxy.java:78) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar!/:na]
at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$Adapter$3.run(TransportService.java:468) ~[elasticsearch-1.5.2.jar!/:na]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.NodeDisconnectedException: [NodeName-apsrp5470][inet[/10.222.146.127:9300]][indices:data/write/index] disconnected**
```

Thread Dumps :-

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x00000007bd824f48> (a org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture$Sync.get(BaseFuture.java:279)
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.BaseFuture.get(BaseFuture.java:118)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.AdapterActionFuture.actionGet(AdapterActionFuture.java:45)
at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate.index(ElasticsearchTemplate.java:519)
```

Comment: your client version is different from server. Client is 1.5.2 whereas server is 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error too. Here are the few cases where `NoNodeException` Occurs:

1) When we use HTTP port `9200` instead of `9300` on the JAVA client API in transport client.
  2) When `Elasticsearch jar` and `Java Client Jar` version are mismatched.
  3) Different Java version on Elasticsearch node and Client server.
  4) When garbage collection is triggered , there would be a span of `stop the world` time. In this span the Java process will freeze and the node would give the same `No node exception`.
 [Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/1.x/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html#_os_and_process_sections)

Please check these points.

Answer (score 0):

The 1.3.2.RELEASE version of the `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` only works with Elasticsearch 1.5.2.

You have two solutions:

1. You downgrade your ES to 1.5.2 (instead of 1.7.3)
2. You use version 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT of `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` which is based on ES 1.7.3

Answer (score 0):

Option is to try using another library if ES cannot be downgraded.