# Elasticsearch 5 Java Client giving "NoNodeAvailableException"

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am using **Elasticsearch 5.2** and **Spring Boot 1.5.1**. I am connecting to it via the Java client in a Spring app. When I connect to it on port `9300` or `9200` and I get `NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available`. In my Java client, I have set the `client.transport.sniff` property as `true`. On sending a request to it via cURL on port 9200, it is working correctly. I have 4 nodes in a single cluster and I cannot connect to any of them. My configuration file has all of the default values in the `network` division except for `network.host` which has `eth0` `inet addr` as the value.

I am using Gradle. My dependencies are:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.2.0')
compile('org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.2.0')
compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7')
compile('org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7')
```

My code for connecting to the Elasticsearch cluster:

```
@Bean
public TransportClient elasticClient() {
    org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
        .put("cluster.name", "TestCluster")
            .build();
    TransportClient client = null;
    try {
        client = new org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress(
                InetAddress.getByName("54.175.155.56"), 9200));
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return client;
}
```

My ES logs when ES starts are:

```
[2017-02-15T10:37:40,664][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [ip-10-0-29-2] publish_address {10.0.29.2:9300}, bound_addresses {10.0.29.2:9300}
[2017-02-15T10:37:40,669][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [ip-10-0-29-2] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
[2017-02-15T10:37:43,856][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [ip-10-0-29-2] detected_master {kafka-stage}{sTIeF8gGTNam0oNW8dkbbA}{TTX6FIRtRp-gDemYY-22Sg}{10.0.20.71}{10.0.20.71:9300}, added {{kafka-stage-2}{jl3oLGgMQ1yxhdMMy65k_g}{ibV8BApjRByUOpDDncddyQ}{10.0.51.31}{10.0.51.31:9300},{ip-10-0-40-144}{t-_THs3wQbC_k9eivDo5eQ}{v-UYoYgXQ265QkdYhtiPYA}{10.0.40.144}{10.0.40.144:9300},{kafka-stage}{sTIeF8gGTNam0oNW8dkbbA}{TTX6FIRtRp-gDemYY-22Sg}{10.0.20.71}{10.0.20.71:9300},}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [master {kafka-stage}{sTIeF8gGTNam0oNW8dkbbA}{TTX6FIRtRp-gDemYY-22Sg}{10.0.20.71}{10.0.20.71:9300} committed version [98]])
[2017-02-15T10:37:44,009][INFO ][o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [ip-10-0-29-2] publish_address {10.0.29.2:9200}, bound_addresses {10.0.29.2:9200}
[2017-02-15T10:37:44,009][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [ip-10-0-29-2] started
```

The answers at these questions don't solve my problem:

1. [Java ElasticSearch None of the configured nodes are available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25912572/java-elasticsearch-none-of-the-configured-nodes-are-available)
2. [Elasticsearch - NoNodeAvailableException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33691858/elasticsearch-nonodeavailableexception)
3. [Elasticsearch NoNodeAvailableException issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453590/elasticsearch-nonodeavailableexception-issue)

Comment: Can you share your POM?

Comment: @Val I have added my dependencies.

Comment: could you share you java code that connecting to the ES?

Comment: @Mysterion I have added the Java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The node to which I was connecting to was only a master node. It had `node.ingest` and `node.data` as `false`. On connecting to a node which had `node.ingest` as `true` and removing the `client.transport.sniff` setting in the Java client, I was able to connect to the ES cluster.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue. But I think I only have one node. Could you give me some suggestions?

Comment: @niaomingjian set `node.ingest` as `true` in your master node.

Comment: I just have one ES instance. My question is here https://stackoverflow.com/q/47050107/4983501

Answer (score 5):

In your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration file you need to make sure to bind to the correct host and have the following setting:

```
network.host: 54.175.155.56
```

Also in your Java code, since you're using the transport client you need to use the port 9300 (for TCP communication) and not 9200, which is meant for HTTP communication (e.g. via curl)

```
    client = new org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress(
            InetAddress.getByName("54.175.155.56"), 9300));
                                                     ^
                                                     |
                                                change this
```

Comment: I use the `eth0 inet addr` as the `network.host` value. Using the DNS IP does not alow me to connect to the cluster. I tried using both as an array then I got the error: `BindException: Cannot assign requested address`. Using port `9300` gives the same result.

Comment: Can you update your question with the ES logs you see when ES starts, especially the line where "publish_host" and "bind_host" appear.

Comment: Added them when I start ES using only the `eth0 inet addr` as `network.host`

Comment: Then you need to use `10.0.29.2:9300` in your Java code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I am able to connect to ES using cURL but not through Java.

Comment: cURL uses port 9200, whereas your Transport client **must** use port 9300, can you confirm you're using 9300 in your code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 9300

Comment: Can you use `Settings.EMPTY` instead of the settings you currently have? i.e. remove sniff and cluster name settings.

Comment: The same thing, did not work. I get the additional message: `not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...`

Comment: Ok, then just add `cluster.name` and no sniff, make sure the cluster name matches the one in your config.

Comment: Do you run your curl on the same host as where your Java client is running ?

Comment: Yes, I run it at the same host.

Comment: Can you ping 54.175.155.56 from the machine where you run your Java app? What do you see?

Comment: I can't ping because that port is not open. 9300 is.

Comment: When I telnet to that port, it is connecting.

Comment: @khateeb did you ever fix this one?

Answer (score 1):

Most Probably the answer of this question is clustername may be different from the elasticsearch.yml, do configure that and in elasticsearch it uses *two ports*: they are **9200** which provides access through http and **9300** is used for accessing Elasticsearch through the internal transport protocol, which is used by **Java Transport Client.**