# elasticsearch 5.5.3 Java client API NoNodeAvailableException with docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I downloaded the image from [Install Elasticsearch with Docker](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/docker.html)
and run the following command to start up:

```
docker run -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.5.3
```

Using [Transport Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.5/transport-client.html) to access it.

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
        .put("cluster.name", "docker-cluster").build();
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress(my-elastic, 9300)));
```

I did nothing else, but I got a NoNodeAvailableException error:

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{9VJdNJv9S7O3Pchx2z2wEg}{my-elastic}{192.168.99.100:9300}]]
```

What should I do to fix this issue?

Startup logs:

```
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,040][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,178][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [h-M1oJa] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [8.3gb], net total_space [17.8gb], spins? [possibly], types [ext4]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,179][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [h-M1oJa] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,184][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [h-M1oJa] derived from node ID [h-M1oJaUTY-G0ezl-89-cw]; set [node.name] to override
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,185][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.5.2], pid[1], build[b2f0c09/2017-08-14T12:33:14.154Z], OS[Linux/4.4.52-boot2docker/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_141/25.141-b15]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:52,185][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] JVM arguments [-Xms2g, -Xmx2g, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -Djdk.io.permissionsUseCanonicalPath=true, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Dlog4j.skipJansi=true, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [ingest-common]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [lang-expression]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [lang-groovy]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [lang-mustache]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,225][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [lang-painless]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [parent-join]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [percolator]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [reindex]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [transport-netty3]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] loaded module [transport-netty4]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:54,226][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [h-M1oJa] no plugins loaded
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:57,851][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [h-M1oJa] using discovery type [zen]
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:59,062][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:59,062][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [h-M1oJa] starting ...
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:45:59,376][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [h-M1oJa] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300}
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:46:02,520][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [h-M1oJa] new_master {h-M1oJa}{h-M1oJaUTY-G0ezl-89-cw}{dYFfXS4vToOMMfAEWy57ig}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:46:02,588][INFO ][o.e.h.n.Netty4HttpServerTransport] [h-M1oJa] publish_address {172.18.0.8:9200}, bound_addresses {[::]:9200}
my-elastic               | [2017-11-01T07:46:02,591][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [h-M1oJa] started
```

I could access http://192.168.99.100:9200 with Postman.

```
{
    "name": "-v9MHhY",
    "cluster_name": "docker-cluster",
    "cluster_uuid": "Ig6tY10oSc6hAbpLqo9fcg",
    "version": {
        "number": "5.5.3",
        "build_hash": "9305a5e",
        "build_date": "2017-09-07T15:56:59.599Z",
        "build_snapshot": false,
        "lucene_version": "6.6.0"
    },
    "tagline": "You Know, for Search"
}
```

telnet 192.168.99.100:9200 is OK.
telnet 192.168.99.100:9300 is OK.
telnet can access these two ports.

And I'm using spring boot2.0.0M5. The default version of elasticsearch is 5.5.3.

Comment: `publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}` -- may be transport client tries to send requests to itself?

Comment: how to configure `publish_address`

Comment: try to set `network.host` to container's IP address, I see it is 192.168.99.100

Comment: what is `network.host`? Where can I configure it? Could you give me information about this?

Comment: using `-e "network.host=0.0.0.0" ` in `docker run` still doesn't work.  The log is `[o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Y5H-_ML] publish_address {172.17.0.2:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300}`  now.

Comment: Elasticsearch chosen ip adress of internal docker's network.Try to set hostname or ip that will be accessible outside of container

Comment: using `-e "network.host=192.168.99.100" ` in `docker run` still doesn't work. The log is [o.e.t.TransportService ] [Y5H-_ML] publish_address {192.168.99.100:9300}, bound_addresses {[::]:9300} now.

Comment: Then you should look into logs of both Elasticsearch and your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure `network.host: 0.0.0.0` on elasticsearch.yml

Common mistakes:

- Forgot to define `network.host` on the machine
- `cluster.name` changed
- Firewall issues with `port 9300`

**References:**

[network.host](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/important-settings.html#network.host)

> The network.host setting explained in Commonly used network settings is a shortcut which sets the bind host and the publish host at the same time. In advanced used cases, such as when running behind a proxy server, you may need to set these settings to different values:
>
> network.bind_host
>
> This specifies which network interface(s) a node should bind to in order to listen for incoming requests. A node can bind to multiple interfaces, e.g. two network cards, or a site-local address and a local address. Defaults to network.host.
>
> network.publish_host
>
> The publish host is the single interface that the node advertises to other nodes in the cluster, so that those nodes can connect to it. Currently an Elasticsearch node may be bound to multiple addresses, but only publishes one. If not specified, this defaults to the “best” address from network.host, sorted by IPv4/IPv6 stack preference, then by reachability. If you set a network.host that results in multiple bind addresses yet rely on a specific address for node-to-node communication, you should explicitly set network.publish_host.

[Network Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#modules-network)

> network.host
>
> The node will bind to this hostname or IP address and publish (advertise) this host to other nodes in the cluster. Accepts an IP address, hostname, a special value, or an array of any combination of these.
>
> Defaults to *local*.

[HTTP-Settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-http.html#modules-http)

> http.bind_host
>
> The host address to bind the HTTP service to. Defaults to http.host (if set) or network.bind_host.
>
> http.publish_host
>
> The host address to publish for HTTP clients to connect to. Defaults to http.host (if set) or network.publish_host.
>
> http.host
>
> Used to set the http.bind_host and the http.publish_host Defaults to http.host or network.host.